# How to Set `on-tap` Behavior of </paper-button> with Javascript in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, appendchild

I am trying to append a `paper-button` to tho DOM on-the-fly with a function in Poylmer 2.x.

I would like this new button to call another function when tapped.

```
appendNodeToDom() {
  let prop = this.result[i]['someProperty'];
  let node = document.createElement("paper-button");
  let button = document.createTextNode(prop);

  button.ontap = this.go(); // what is the proper syntax for this?

  node.appendChild(button);
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(node);
}

go() {
  console.log('go');
}
```

Also tried:

```
button.addEventListener("click", this.go());
button.addEventListener("tap", this.go());
```

How do I set the "on-tap" behavior with Javascript in Polymer 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you're calling `button` the text node *inside* the `paper-button` and setting the event listener on that node which - being a `Text` node - doesn't fire events (apart from some [exceptions](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents)).

Also, you're passing `this.go()` as callback to `addEventListener`. This means that `this.go()` *is executed* and then the return value is passed as callback (in this case `undefined` because after console.log you're not returning anything). You should instead pass the identifier of the function without calling it:

```
addEventListener('tap', this.go);
```

All together:

```
appendNodeToDom() {
  let prop = this.result[i]['someProperty'];
  let button = document.createElement('paper-button');
  let text = document.createTextNode(prop);

  button.appendChild(text);
  button.addEventListener('tap', this.go); // Add the listener to button
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(node);
}

go() {
  console.log('go');
}
```

---

Just a small note: keep in mind that Polymer has a lot of tools to avoid performing direct DOM manipulation. If you just need to add a button to a list you could consider a solution where `dom-repeat` renders the buttons and the changes are made on the underlying array property.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is a special case where the `DOM` renders differently based on the length of `this.result`.

Comment: @Matthew if you find this answer as helpful, please accept it.